# JavaEE: 'SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT' without marking the JTA transaction for rollback when fails?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, locking, jta

I'm trying to use 'SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT' in JavaEE (using JPA). This is how I do it:

```
props.put("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 0);
em.find(MyEntity.class, id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ, props);
```

This goes well except for one thing: If this fails (couldn't acquire the lock), then a PessimisticLockException is thrown instead of a LockTimeoutException (which is thrown if any other positive timeout is set), which causes the transaction (JTA transaction) to be marked for rollback.

I've tried using native queries instead, but it yields the same result.
I'm using Weblogic 12.1 with EclipseLink (tried TopLink as well, no difference).

Is there any way to execute a 'SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT' without the JTA transaction being marked for rollback in JavaEE when the execution fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please log a bug and vote for it.

You can probably fix it by creating your own subclass of OraclePlatform and overriding isLockTimeoutException().

You could also execute the query as a DatabaseQuery to avoid the rollback.

```
em.unwrap(Session.class).executeQuery(((JpaQuery)query).getDatabaseQuery())
```

Comment: Where should I log a bug? At EclipseLink? TopLink? And is this really a bug? What the specification has to say about this (I guess nothing)?

Comment: Yes, it is a real bug. For EclipseLink http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching.  If you are using TopLink and have support, then you could also contact Oracle support.  In addition to the locking fix, I think EclipseLink should also provide a query hint or setting to avoid any error forcing a rollback.

Comment: Another thing; It seems that when executing the query this way I can't set bind variables, i.e 'setParameter' is being ignored. Is there any way to workaround it (other than not using bind variables)?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to skip a locked row. This is the alternate of

> select * from student where student id = n for update nowait

findStudnt method throws error if row is already locked. If there is no error call updateStudent method to update student entity else log the error for audit.

```
@Override
public Student findStudent(final Long studentId) {
    TypedQuery<Student> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("from Student s where s.studentId =:studentId", Student.class);
    query.setParameter("studentId", studentId);
    query.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    query.setHint(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_LOCK_TIMEOUT, ZERO_NUMBER);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void updateStudent(Student student) {
    makePersistent(student);
    getEntityManager().flush();
}
```